# BLoC is not created and triggered when the home page is destroyed and recreated

Tags: flutter, routes, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am registering a user as a member and need to redirect user to home screen on successful registration. The `registerMemberSuccess` state is received and I redirect the user to home page using `auto_route`. However, the HomeBloc does not trigger the event. I have checked the Flutter inspector.

In the inspector, there is no `HomePage`, only `MaterialApp` after  `context.router.removeLast();` is fired. However, when I push a new route, the BLoC simply does not fire the event.

I cannot add the `HomeBloc` to top of `MaterialApp` because it can only be used after user is logged in. Similarly, I do not want to manually refresh home bloc each time either. What could I do to alleviate this issue?

**MemberRegistration snippet**

```dart
 registerMemberSuccess: (_) {
              AppAlertDialog.showAlertDialog(
                context: context,
                content: 'Member registered successfully.',
                barrierDismissible: false,
                onActionPressed: () {
                  // Remove all entries in navigation
                  context.router.popUntilRoot();
                  context.router.removeLast();

                  // Add a new stack
                  context.router.push(const HomeRoute());
                },
              );
            },
```

**HomePage/Route**

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<HomeBloc>(
      create: (context) =>
          HomeBloc(getHomePageDataUseCase: getIt<GetHomePageDataUseCase>())
            ..add(HomeEvent.fetchHomePageDataPressed()),
      child: ScreenTypeLayout.builder(
        mobile: (mobileContext) => const HomeMobileWidget(),
        tablet: (tabletContext) => const HomeTabletWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. `HomeBloc(getHomePageDataUseCase: getIt<GetHomePageDataUseCase>())
            ..add(HomeEvent.fetchHomePageDataPressed()` <- when you say the event is not fired you mean this add()?
When I have injection to do in the bloc it usually is something like this:
```getIt<HomeBloc>()..add(WhatEvaEvent)``` so I'm not sure if you bloc creation is correct here

Comment: The Bloc Creation is correct here. I am only injecting the usecases. Not the BLoC itself. The whole widget is destroyed. And, I am recreating the page. However, the  BLoC retains the old data.

Comment: I am mistaken here, the BLoC is not retaining old data. The whole widget is not recreated here.